# What is the difference between どうしたって and 是非?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I have recently stumbled across the word どうしたって which according to the dictionary means "by all means, no matter what, at any rate". I was wondering how its usage differs from 是非 "certainly, without fail" as they both have very similar meanings. Does one have a positive connotation and the other negative? Are they interchangeable or not? If anyone could tell me the difference I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome Ethan!  Though your intro and greeting were definitely well-received, I have edited them out because we tend to keep questions as brief as possible and to the point.  But this is certainly a good question, and the type of content we enjoy around here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. These are used in different types of sentences.

どうしたって (or どうしても) is usually followed by something undesirable or inevitable.

- どうしたって無理だ。
  No matter what, it's impossible.
- 他人の気持ちを理解するのはどうしたって難しい。
  At any rate, it's hard to understand the feelings of other people.

是非 is an adverb that is used exclusively when you strongly invite or recommend something. I feel it's weaker than 必ず ("without fail"), though.

- 是非パーティーに来てください。
  Please come to our party!
- このゲームは是非プレイするべきです。
  You should definitely play this game.
- 是非！
  Yes, please do! / Definitely!
  <sub>(after being asked whether they should do something)</sub>

(Note that both どうしたって and 是非 have other usages.)

Comment: Does 是非とも carry any additional weight over just 是非?

Comment: @istrasci 是非とも is simply stronger, but I think 是非 is usually enough. Overusing 是非とも may sound like a salesperson's talk.

Comment: Would you ever say 是非 with friends or is it mainly for polite speech?

Comment: @OtheJared 是非 is not particularly formal, but something like 絶対 may be preferred in slangy speech.